# Introduced intermediate variable in structured binding definition?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, structured-bindings

In [[dcl.struct.bind] 9.6.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.struct.bind#4.sentence-9), there is definition of structured binding when initializer is a class type with `std​::​tuple_­size<E>​::​value` properly defined:

> ... variables are introduced with unique names *ri* as follows:
> *S Ui ri = initializer ;*
> Each *vi* is the name of an lvalue of type *Ti* that refers to the object bound to *ri*;
> the referenced type is *Ti*.

My question is why is it necessary to introduce *ri*, can't we define the identifier *vi* directly as reference to the result of `get<i>(e)`?

Comment: I would guess the reason is because otherwise you'd get dangling references, as the lifetime of (the resulting object of) the initializer ends with the declaration.

Comment: @PasserBy I guess the initializer (not the initializer in the above quote, but in the whole structured binding declaration) has already been extended or copied by the introduced `e` variable? Then the subobjects will never be dangling?

Comment: Oh no, my quote is from C++20. And in [C++17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.struct.bind#:~:text=Given%20the%20type,.), _vi_ really is defined as a reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The intent is to disallow redeclaring structured bindings as references. See [CWG 2313](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2313.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. May I ask where can I find the information like git blame about which part of the standard is changed due to which proposal for what reason?

Comment: @Masquue The source of the standard is available at https://github.com/cplusplus/draft. You can literally use `git blame` with that.

Comment: @Masquue Isn't the question about why introduce `ri` at all and not just say that `vi` is an lvalue with the same type and result as `get<i>(e)`?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Yes, it's about why introduce `ri`. I don't get what's your question...

Comment: @Masquue _Yes, it's about why introduce `ri`_ Then I don't get how this answer answers your question.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Previous wording allows redeclaring the structured binding which is disallowed by current wording. I think this answer and the link says it clearly...